# APK Expansion File Localization?

Tags: android

I have some very large (650MB) content files (video, audio) in about 4 different locales.

I want to use APK Expansion Files but they do not seem to support localization.

It seems we can have seperate application listings in Google Play as long as they have different application names (app listing filtered per locale).

What I do not understand is, if you upload the same application (in seperate application listings, same binary, same version), how does the device know where to get the expansion files from?

For instance, suppose I have 2 localized applications with seperate application listings:-

My App (UK) + Expansion File (UK)
My App (DE) + Expansion File (DE)

If the application I upload for both listings is the same binary, same version, I can't see how Google Play will know how to associate the app installed, with either of those listings?

This problem occured to me during testing whilst setting up 2 listings for DE and UK with the same draft APK.

Does anyone have any experience with this and is there a recommended approach? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to upload it as two seperate listings, each application needs to have a different package name.  Otherwise when you try to upload the second one, you'll get an error.

When you upload an APK, you also upload the expansion file, which is then associated with that particular APK (via package name).  The device gets the expansion file from Google Play, which tracks that association.

All that said, there are disadvantages to uploading two identical APK's-  Your ratings will be split across two apps, for instance, and ranking will suffer since neither one will get as many ratings as if you only had one APK covering both situations.

Comment: "In order for you to upload it as two seperate listings, each application needs to have a different package name. Otherwise when you try to upload the second one, you'll get an error." - This is incorrect, please check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#publishing Also, you can try it on the Google Play console, I have confirmed you can publish 2 applications with the same package name as long as they have different application names

Comment: I mean packagename as in what's defined the "package" attribute of the Manifest tag in your AndroidManifest, not the packagename following the "package" keyword at the top of your sourcefiles.  Usually the same, but don't have to be.  Could you link to your app (or just name it) ? If it's actually possible I'd like to take a look.

Comment: @AlexanderLucas You can publish multiple .apks under the same manifest-"package" name [Multiple APK Support in Android Market](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html)/[Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) to support different configurations and keep apk size smaller.

Comment: @zapl that is correct, it seems however if you want to support APK per locale (and also benefit from expansion file per locale) you have to have a seperate app listing :( Looks like my best option would be to not use expansion files alltogether, which is a shame really.

Comment: zapl-  Multiple APK support requires that one of at least the following is different per apk:  GL texture support, minSdkVersion, and supported screen sizes.  You can't use the multiple APK feature if locale is the only thing that's different.

Comment: @AlexanderLucas if you are now agreeing that you can upload two different apps with same package name (and in answer to your question I mean manifest package) could you update you answer. Also, FYI in order to be more specific you need to sign your app with the same signature to have the same package name and also your app name needs to be unique (the app name you provide in your app listing in the developer console)

Comment: My previous comment was discussing multiple APKs, which don't solve your problem, as you've already mentioned.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help Alexander, you are right, it looks like I have no other choice than to use a different way to download content other than Expansion Files because I simply cannot pack all this content into one app :(

Comment: @AlexanderLucas The way I understood the localized apk approach is: use the same listing / package name but use a different application name so you have a difference per .apk. That means imo that each apk can be assigned an expansion file the same way it works if you provide different apks per e.g. screensize. The only difference is that you need to set the language->apk link via the Google Play console.

Comment: @zapl how do you set up the language->apk link I do not see an option to do this in Google Play?

Comment: I don't know but the localization [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#publishing) you mentioned says "Upload your .apk file or files to Google Play, selecting the appropriate languages as you upload."

Comment: Cool, I see that but, I think its misleading as there is no option to select language when uploading an apk, shame.